# How often is the value in the database in Laravel Equolent

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner. I have small problem with Laravel Equolent.

I have migrations:

```
Schema::create('datas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('number');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and model:

```
class Data extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'number'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'date'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'number'=>'integer',
    ];
}
```

Normalny I make this code:

```
Data::get();
```

and this is return me all record from DB.

I need information how often does the number appear in the database.

For example:

```
Data->where('number', 1)->get();
Data->where('number', 15)->get();
Data->where('number', 55)->get();
```

etc

how wany can I count this result? ->count()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to count all the records in your `Data` model, you can use this code:

```
$count = Data::count();
```

But if you want to count specific `number`, try this:

```
$count = Data::where('number', $number)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

in the controller file Data::count();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).